# Duplication of Piped output

Tags: c

Can someone please explain to me why my output has duplicates in it from the ls command. The normal operation of `ls -l | sort` does not give me a duplicated output so what could be the issue?

Essentially i'm trying to pipe the output from one command and enter it into another command. The program works so far, but the output is displaying duplicate data. Plus and explanation of why I would need to do a close after dup2 would be really helpful :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


// function declarations
void executeLs(int data_pipe[]);
void executeSort(int data_pipe[]);

int main(){

        int data_pipe[2]; // array storing the file descriptors
        int childls_pid; // ls child process
        int childSort_pid; // sort child process
        int rc; // return vaue of the pipe
        int child_status1;
        int child_status2;

        rc = pipe(data_pipe);
        if(rc == -1){
            perror("pipe");
            exit(1);
        }


        childls_pid = fork();
        childSort_pid = fork();

        // Ls Child process
        switch(childls_pid) {
        case -1:
                perror("fork childLs Error");
                exit(1);
        case 0:
                // inside of child process
                executeLs(data_pipe);
                exit(0);
        default:
            break;
        }

        // Sort child process
        switch(childSort_pid) {
        case -1:
                perror("fork childSort Error");
                exit(1);
        case  0:
                executeSort(data_pipe);
                exit(0);
        default:
                wait(&child_status2);
        }
        return 0;
}
void executeLs(int data_pipe[]){

    // Closes the read file descriptor
    close(data_pipe[0]);

    dup2(data_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    // confused as to why this is necessary
    close(data_pipe[1]);

    execlp("ls", "ls", "-1", NULL);
}
void executeSort(int data_pipe[]){

    // close the write file descriptor
    close(data_pipe[1]);

    dup2(data_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(data_pipe[0]);
    execlp("sort","sort", NULL);
}
```

Comment: You need to close the pipe FDs in the parent after you fork the children.

Comment: Isn't that what i'm doing inside of my main function? Wait, let me get this straight. If I close out of my pipes inside of my child processess, that doesnt close out of the pipe function inside of my parent process?

Comment: You should always call `_exit` (not `exit`) after a failed `exec`*. `exit` flushes stdio buffers. If you're `exec`ing, you're current process has a copy of stdio buffers that was never meant to be flushed.

Comment: Hmm, after reading up on the two. exit(1) just lets the computer know that the program ended with errors, while _exit terminates the calling process and the process parent is sent a signal. Did I get that right? @PSkocik

Comment: Suppose you printf in the parent. Because stdout is buffered, you don't actually invoke the system call just yet, but instead write to a buffer that'll get flushed (=the actual syscall) when full. If you fork without prior flushing, the buffer gets duplicated. That's OK if you fork to exec because a succesful exec will wipe the process image. If the exec fails however, then you don't want to flush the stdout buffer duplicate. `exit` will flush (and call exit handlers). `_exit` will exit right away.

Comment: Signals don't play a role here. A parent always gets a signal (SIGCHLD) when the status of its child changes (unless it explicitly chooses not to be notified).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you're forking more processes than you intended. When you do:

```
    childls_pid = fork();
    childSort_pid = fork();
```

you're doing the second `fork()` in both the original parent process and the process created by the first `fork()`. So you now have the following process tree:

```
parent
    childls
        childSort
    childSort
```

In both `childls` and `childls->childSort`, `childls_pid` is 0, so they both execute the `case 0:` clause that runs `executeLs()`.

You need to move the second `fork` into code that only runs in the original parent. You can simply move it to after the first `switch` statement.

The reason you need to close the pipe FDs is because a pipe isn't really closed until all processes that have it open close it. If the child process has the write end of its pipe open, that will keep it from reading `EOF` on the pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// function declarations
void executeLs(int data_pipe[]);
void executeSort(int data_pipe[]);

int main(){

    int data_pipe[2]; // array storing the file descriptors
    int childls_pid; // ls child process
    int childSort_pid; // sort child process
    int rc; // return vaue of the pipe
    int child_status1;
    int child_status2;

    rc = pipe(data_pipe);
    if(rc == -1){
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    childls_pid = fork();

    // Ls Child process
    switch(childls_pid) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork childLs Error");
        exit(1);
    case 0:
        // inside of child process
        executeLs(data_pipe);
        exit(0);
    default:
        break;
    }

    childSort_pid = fork();

    // Sort child process
    switch(childSort_pid) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork childSort Error");
        exit(1);
    case  0:
        executeSort(data_pipe);
        exit(0);
    default:
        wait(&child_status2);
    }
    return 0;
}

void executeLs(int data_pipe[]){

    // Closes the read file descriptor
    close(data_pipe[0]);

    dup2(data_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    // confused as to why this is necessary
    close(data_pipe[1]);

    execlp("ls", "ls", "-1", NULL);
}

void executeSort(int data_pipe[]){

    // close the write file descriptor
    close(data_pipe[1]);

    dup2(data_pipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(data_pipe[0]);
    execlp("sort","sort", NULL);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a million, you cleared up a lot for me! I'm just learning all of this today.